# how to convert rows into column using awk?

Tags: awk

I have an input contains of 36 lines like this:

```
822
526006
1343315205
1.4.2
32
0.000000
13.048815
...
0
0
0
```

That is the output from memcache stats command. So it is not from a file. How can I convert those lines into a columns of a single row. I don't want to use temp file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '{printf("%s ", $0)}'
```

using a pipe:

```
whatever_your_command | awk '{printf("%s ", $0)}'
```

The advantage of using `printf()` is that it gives you complete control over the output format/spacing/etc of your data.

--

*Testing*

```
822
526006
1343315205
1.4.2
32
0.000000
13.048815
```

data in file `data.txt`:

```
awk '{printf("%s ", $0)}' data.txt
```

yields:

```
822 526006 1343315205 1.4.2 32 0.000000 13.048815
```

Comment: it is strange that the previous pipe gives those numbers as numbers not string. So I have to do "%d" instead of %s to get it work. So my final command looks like: echo "stats" | nc 10.34.10.38 11211 | awk '{printf("%d ",$3)} END {print ""}'

Comment: @SeanNguyen Thanks for the feedback, glad you were able to make the necessary adjustment for this solution to work.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this without awk:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file
echo $(<file)
xargs echo < file
perl -pe 's/\n/ /' < file
```

Example:

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' < data.txt
822 526006 1343315205 1.4.2 32 0.000000 13.048815
$ echo $(<data.txt)
822 526006 1343315205 1.4.2 32 0.000000 13.048815
$ xargs echo < data.txt
822 526006 1343315205 1.4.2 32 0.000000 13.048815
$ perl -pe 's/\n/ /' < data.txt
822 526006 1343315205 1.4.2 32 0.000000 13.048815
```

Answer (score 4):

```
anuj@test:~$ cat num
1
2
3
4
5
anuj@test:~$ cat num |xargs
1 2 3 4 5
anuj@test:~$
```

cat and xargs would be more than enough i guess

Answer (score 2):

It can be a single character `awk` program

```
seq 10 | awk -v ORS=" " 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
input | sed ':a;N;{s/\n/ /};ba'
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can use something like this.

```
input="822
526006
1343315205
1.4.2
32
0.000000
13.048815"
```

Then use a simple for loop.

```
for row in $(echo "$input");do echo -en "$row ";done;echo
```

Outputs

```
822 526006 1343315205 1.4.2 32 0.000000 13.048815
```

Note that last echo is to avoid having your prompt on the same line, remove if you use this in a script accordingly.